# Docker base image that supports the most architectures?

Tags: docker, cpu-architecture

I'm looking to publish my Docker image for as many CPU architectures as possible through docker buildx. Currently I'm using [`alpine:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/?tab=tags) but it supports only 8 architectures.

I've looked at https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world?tab=tags and noticed that it supports 11 architectures (I suspect it's just using `FROM scratch`)

I've noticed that Docker supports the following architectures: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64

My problem is that I can't build and publish an image to Dockerhub for eg. `linux/mips64le` becaue my current base image - alpine - does not publish a `mips64le` image

I probably won't be able to port to some of those architectures because the program I'm trying to dockerize (umurmur) doesn't support them, but thought I'd ask the question in a maximalist way anyway

For my repo's wiki and build steps, see https://github.com/sethidden/umurmur-docker/wiki

Comment: Is the answer just to have a custom Dockerfile for the architectures not supported by alpine? eg for windows/amd64 I could use a custom Dockerfile with the FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:XXX image (https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world)?

Comment: alpine:edge used to support mips64le but they dropped support recently as the architecture is supposedly discontinued